# Iterating over an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm creating an iterator class for my class which is based of an array. Think of it as just an ordinary array with functions that inserts element into the array. So far, I've only come across iterator for Linked List but had no luck figuring out just for ordinary arrays.

```
class ArrayIterator:

    def __init__(self,array):
        self.i = 0

    def __next__(self):
        first = array[0]
        self.i+=1
        return i

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ordinary array"? An [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)? A Numpy array? Or are you talking about plain Python lists? The code you posted is a little puzzling. The `__init__` method takes an arg named `array`, but it does nothing with it.

Comment: @PM 2Ring the ones represented by [None]*size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
class ArrayIterator:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.i = 0
        self.array = array

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            result = self.array[self.i]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.i += 1
            return result

    def __iter__(self):
        return self


my_iter = ArrayIterator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for x in my_iter:
    print(x)
```